# Encapsulating API.ai call into an external javascript function is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, api-design, dialogflow-es

This code works fine:

```
var apiai = require('apiai');
var app = apiai(<token>);

var request = app.textRequest('jacket', {
  'sessionId': 123456
});

request.on('response', function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  console.log(response.result.fulfillment.speech);
  console.log(response.result.metadata.intentName);
});

request.on('error', function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});

request.end();
```

And it produces the following console output:

```
{ id: '2865abde-ac8f-4ac3-816e-483c68f709d0',
  timestamp: '2016-11-08T22:38:56.461Z',
  result:
   { source: 'agent',
     resolvedQuery: 'jacket',
     action: '',
     actionIncomplete: false,
     parameters: {},
     contexts: [ [Object] ],
     metadata:
      { intentId: '357af94f-00b3-4016-a661-732419ddafd6',
        webhookUsed: 'false',
        intentName: 'clothing' },
     fulfillment: { speech: 'clothing2', messages: [Object] },
     score: 0.6 },
  status: { code: 200, errorType: 'success' },
  sessionId: '123456' }
clothing2
clothing
```

However, when I try to break this apart into a function call, things don't work so well:

**File: main.js**

```
 var apiai = require('apiai');
 var app3 = apiai(<token>);

exports.getresponse = function(inputstring){
  var request = app3.textRequest(inputstring, {'sessionId': 123456});
  request.on('response', function(response) {
    return(response);
});
  request.on('error', function(error) {
    return(error);
});
  request.end();
};
```

**File: moda.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var joe = require('./main.js');
console.log(joe.getresponse('jacket'));
app.listen(3000);
```

When I run moda.js (node moda.js), I get only

```
undefined
```

as the console output.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks so much!

Comment: You've publicly exposed your api.ai token in this post. You MUST regenerate that token immediately. https://docs.api.ai/docs/authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`joe.getresponse()` doesn't have an explicit return, thus it has an implicit `return undefined;`

That's why you are seeing `undefined` in your console output.

The reason is a bit complicated, and fundamental to javascript programming, but it has to do with Callbacks, and asynchronous execution of javascript.

With this line here, you are actually adding an anonymous function as a callback. That function doesn't actually get executed until it is invoked (typically in response to an event).

```
  request.on('response', function(response) {
    return(response);
});
```

So while you are returning the response, the scope of that return is not inside the `getresponse()` outer function, but instead inside the `response` event emitter.

Instead, you'll need to capture the Response value in a way you can determinisitcally access it. By supplying your own callback to the `getresponse()` method, that callback will have access to the response object.

It would looks something like this:

**main.js**

```
var apiai = require('apiai');
var app3 = apiai(<token>);

exports.getresponse = function(inputstring,callback){
  var request = app3.textRequest(inputstring, {'sessionId': 123456});
  request.on('response', function(response) {
    callback(null,response);
});
  request.on('error', function(error) {
    callback(error,null);
});
  request.end();
};
```

**moda.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var joe = require('./main.js');
joe.getresponse('jacket', function(error,response) {
     if(error) { console.error(error); }
     console.log(response);
 });
app.listen(3000);
```

Instead of returning the response value, I am invoking a caller supplied callback, which then handles the response (calls console.log).

Comment: When I run this, I get an error referencing onResponse. If I'm reading this right, the function onResponse needs to be defined somewhere, correct? Is this the caller supplied callback that you are referring to?

Comment: NP. Do you understand the underlying issue? It's fundamental to working with JavaScript?

Comment: Well, sorta. I have been trying to wrap my head around asynchronous execution for the last day or so. It turns most of my programming expertise inside out, so it is really not intuitive for me at this point. I can't seem to figure out how to effectively pass variables back and forth anymore. Seems like absolutely everything has to be nested. Which doesn't lend to simple code (aka callback hell). If you have some resources that help transition sequential coders to async, that would be really helpful.

Comment: Try these: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises and https://github.com/caolan/async